# Display entire multiple div on another page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to display multiple divs(entire divs Including css designs) from multiple pages on another page(one page) that has the div class "Paytm".

In this code, there are two divs with the class name "Paytm" and I want to display both of these divs in another page(in one page only).

I want to do this on Blogger(Blogger.com). How can I achieve this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.coupon {
  border: 5px dotted #bbb;
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.promo {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 3px;
}

.expire {
  color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="Paytm">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Company Logo</h3>
  </div>
  <img src="/w3images/hamburger.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
    <h2><b>20% OFF YOUR PURCHASE</b></h2> 
    <p> This is Paytm Coupon 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Use Promo Code: <span class="promo">ABC123</span></p>
    <p class="expire">Expires: Jan 03, 2021</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Google Pay">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Company Logo</h3>
    </div>
    <img src="/w3images/hamburger.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
      <h2><b>20% OFF YOUR PURCHASE</b></h2> 
      <p> This is Google Pay Coupon 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Use Promo Code: <span class="promo">XYZ789</span></p>
      <p class="expire">Expires: Jan 03, 2021</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Paytm">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Company Logo</h3>
    </div>
    <img src="/w3images/hamburger.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
      <h2><b>20% OFF YOUR PURCHASE</b></h2> 
      <p> This is Paytm Coupon 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Use Promo Code: <span class="promo">PQR654</span></p>
      <p class="expire">Expires: Jan 03, 2021</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

In short multiple div from multiple pages (including css designs of those div) to one page only that has class name "paytm".

Hope you understood what I am trying to ask.

Comment: It is not clear what you want Are the two pages on the same origin (domain and port)

Comment: If multiple possible then multiple, if not possible then single origin..